# representing different kind of players in a class

Tags: java

I am  writing a class to represent cricket players. There are four types of cricket players

1 wicket player
2 batsman
3 bowler
4 allrounder

I'm not sure if I am representing the players in the right way

```
public class Player {
  final static int WICKETPLAYER=1;
  final static int BATSMAN=2;
  final static int  BOWLER=3;
  final static int ALLROUNDER=4;
  int currentbatting;
  int bowlerbating;
  int playertype;

  public Player(int i,int currentbatting){
      this.currentbatting=currentbatting;
      playertype=i;

  }

  public String whatTypeOFplayer(){
      switch(playertype){
      case WICKETPLAYER:
          return "wicketplayer" ;
      case BATSMAN:
          return " batsman";
      case BOWLER:
          return "bowler";
      case ALLROUNDER:
          return "allrounder";
          default:
              return "error";
      }
  }


}
```

Comment: this belongs to codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should use enums to represent the player types instead of ints, like

```
enum PlayerType {
 WICKETPLAYER,
 BATSMAN,
 BOWLER,
 ALLROUNDER
}
```

Then you could use the `name()` method to get a string representation of the PlayerType.

If there's more to the player types that just the name (e.g. different behaviour, methods etc.), you might consider creating subclasses of `Player`, like `class WicketPlayer extends Player`.

A third way would be to use composition and add components like `PlayerBehaviour` etc. to the basic player class.

I terms of complexity, I'd say no. 1 is the easiest, whereas no. 3 might be too complex for you right now. So you might try and either use no. 1 or no. 2, depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

You are likely to be better off with an enum and an EnumSet.

```
public Role {
  WICKET_KEEPER, BATSMAN, BOWLER, FIELDER
}

public static final Set<Role> ALL_ROUNDER = EnumSet.allOf(Role.class);
private final EnumSet<Role> roles;
private Role position;

public Player(EnumSet<Role> roles) { this.role = roles; }

public void setPosition(Role role) { this.position = role; }

public String whatTypeOFplayer(){
  return roles.equals(ALL_ROUNDER) ? "allrounder" : roles.toString();
}
```

BTW Its a Wicket Keeper not a Wicket Player 
http://www.cricketscotland.com/system/files/images/13_13.jpg

Answer (score 1):

A better way is to inherit from the class Player, it will allow you a simpler treatment for each player and different behaviors for common actions. for example:

Player.java

```
public class Player {
  int currentbatting;
  int bowlerbating;
  int playertype;

  public Player(int i,int currentbatting){
      this.currentbatting=currentbatting;
      playertype=i;
  }

  public abstract String whatTypeOFplayer() {
    return playertype;
  }
}
```

WicketPlayer.java

```
public WicketPlayer extends Player {
  public WicketPlayer(int i,int currentbatting){
    super(int i,int currentbatting);
    playertype = "wicketplayer";
  }
}
```

Batsman.java

```
public Batsman extends Player {
  public Batsman(int i,int currentbatting){
    super(int i,int currentbatting);
    playertype = "batsman";
  }
}
```

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

use Java Enums: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Answer (score 0):

In this case - and because I smell homework - you should use one base class `Player` and a subclass for each player type.

Example:

```
public abstract class Player {
 // some attributes and methods all players share

 public abstract String whatTypeOfPlayer();
}
```

---

```
public WicketPlayer extends Player {
 @Override
 public String whatTypeOfPlayer() {
   return "Wicket Player";
 }
}
```

---

**Bonus** - then I'd use a factory to create players:

```
public PlayerFactory {
 enum PlayerType {WICKETPLAYER, BATSMAN, BOWLER, ALLROUNDER}

 public static Player createPlayer(PlayerType type, String name) {
   switch(type) {
     case WICKETPLAYER : return new WicketPlayer(name);
     //...
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 5+ use Enum Types [Java Enum Types](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html). According to Effective Java it's not a good practice to use a bunch of constants, instead use Enum.

```
public class Player {

public enum Role{
  WICKETPLAYER,
  BATSMAN,
  BOWLER,
  ALLROUNDER;
}
 final int currentbatting;
 final Role playerRole;

  public Player(final Role role, final int currentbatting){
      this.currentbatting=currentbatting;
      this.playerRole=role;

  }

  public String whatTypeOFplayer(){
      return this.playerRole.toString();
  }
```

}